# Why am I getting stack overflow?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:keol_beta/providers/authservice.dart';
import 'package:keol_beta/screen/home.dart';
import 'package:keol_beta/screen/login.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthService(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Keol Beta',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: MyApp(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false);
  }
}

FutureBuilder<User> mainMethod(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: Provider.of<AuthService>(context).getUser(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      Firebase.initializeApp();
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        if (snapshot.error != null) {
          print("ini error di main");
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        print("Connect Done " + snapshot.toString());
        return snapshot.hasData
            // ? HomePage(currentUser: snapshot.data)
            // ? HomePage()
            // : LoginPage();
            ? LoginPage()
            : HomePage();
      } else {
        print("Connect Failure");
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;

  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {

      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {

      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    if (_error) {
      return showAlertDialog(context, "error");
    }

    
    if (!_initialized) {
      return showAlertDialog(context, "loading");
    }

    return mainMethod(context);
  }
}

showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, String value) {
  
  Widget okButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () {},
  );

  
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Error"),
    content: Text(value),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

So, I'm working on my final project for my bachelor degree, and still new in flutter.
I'm trying to upgrade my dependencies with

```
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
```

before was 0.5.0, in the new, it needed initialized default firebase, and im trying to do it, but somehow it got stack overflow error.

almost 3 days I got nothing, is there any solution?

Comment: Can you post the error log ? We're unable to help you without the stacktrace. Also, firebase_core lastest version is 1.0.1 (see https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core)

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what's wrong with your code.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire), you should run the `await Firebase.initializeApp()` **before** any Firebase calls.

In your code, you are calling it after calling `Provider.of<AuthService>(context).getUser()` which I suppose (as there is no code of this file) uses the Firebase Auth code.

You should call `await Firebase.initializeApp()` before running your app with the `await` keyword as `Firebase.initializeApp()` returns a `Future`. It's important that this Future is completed before going further and calling a Firebase method on uninitialized object.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthService(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: its still got some stackoverflowm, there some changes rn, its written that :
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib\main.dart:23

Comment: Try removing the `theme` parameter to see if there is something wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try init firebase app before auth service:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthService(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```